# Bluetooth audio control window on Windows 7 - Make it always visible?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have my smartphone paired to my Windows 7 PC with bluetooth, to play audio (music) from the phone on the PC's speakers.

While this pairing is active, I have a system tray / notification area icon that looks like a white arrow on a blue circle, that when clicked, shows information about the music that's currently playing along with playback controls, which looks like this:

[image: Bluetooth remote control audio playback window]

Whenever that window loses the focus, it disappears / auto-hides.  Whenever a new music track starts playing, the window reappears for about two seconds, then automatically hides itself again.

This is all great, except the behavior I'd like is for that window to remain visible all the time.  If that isn't possible, I'd like for it to remain visible for a longer period of time when a new track begins playing.

How can I do either or both of the following with this bluetooth audio playback control window on Windows 7:

1. Make the window always remain visible, and not auto-hide when it loses the focus? (Preferred)
2. Or, make the window remain visible for a longer period of time when it becomes visible for a period of time when a new music track starts playing?

Comment: Does right clicking on the icon give you any options?

Comment: Nothing helpful. It has: Show status, play/Pause, Stop, Next, Previous, Next Group, Previous Group, Disconnect. No "Properties" or "Auto Hide" or anything like that though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'Customize icons that appear in the Taskbar' feature:

Step 1 : Find the icon on the System Tray and Click it, it should have a tool tip saying 'Show hidden icons'

Step 2: You will encounter a window like this:

[image]

Step 3: Click on 'Customize'

Step 4: The 'Notifications Icons' window opens:

[image]

Step 5: Try toggling the options against the program you want to modify

Comment: I have "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar" checked. The problem isn't that the system tray icon disappears (it doesn't); the problem is that the audio control window that's tied to that system tray icon hides itself when I don't want it to. Thanks for the suggestion though!