# Where is the Bluetooth audio control window in Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth

Earlier versions of Windows had a very nice feature where they could control the audio playback from a paired phone, or even direct the audio output from the phone to the PC's speakers (over BT), using the AVRCP and A2DP profiles, respectively. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/686042/bluetooth-audio-control-window-on-windows-7-make-it-always-visible) shows the window in question on Win7.

I can't find that window on Win10 at all, or any substitute for it. Is it just hidden somewhere? Is it just a problem with Bluetooth support in either the phone or laptop (I'm running Insider Fast ring, so this is possible, but I haven't seen it in a few builds now)? Did they just remove this very useful feature?

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: @CBHacking - did you find the solution? I have the same problem. There is a suggested solution [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-my-windows-10-PC-as-Bluetooth-speakers-for-my-Android-phone) but it seems to be for Windows Vista.